# Type or Class for a Pointer in a Linked List in Fortran

Tags: pointers, linked-list, fortran, polymorphism, intel-fortran

I am confused about the usage of `TYPE` and `CLASS` in defining a linked list with type bound procedure in Fortran. The following simple program causes segmentation fault in `get_num_nodes` function. However, if I change the declaration of the pointer `next` from `CLASS` to `TYPE`, the program ends normally.

The segmentation fault occurs when I build it with `ifort` (version 14.0.2).
If I build it with gfortran (version 4.8.4 and 7.2.0), both cases of `CLASS` and `TYPE` end normally.

What is wrong about using `CLASS` in declaring the `next` pointer? How can I understand the problem? Or, is something wrong in a different part of the code?

`tll.f90`

```
MODULE tll
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE

  PUBLIC LLnode, add_node_at_head

  TYPE LLnode
     PRIVATE
     INTEGER                                  :: idx
     !TYPE(LLnode),                   POINTER :: next => null()
     ! .. using this declaration with TYPE works.
     CLASS(LLnode),                   POINTER :: next => null()
     ! .. this declaration with CLASS causes segmentation fault with 
     ! ifort. 
   CONTAINS
     PROCEDURE :: get_num_nodes
  END type LLnode

! ================================================================
CONTAINS
! ================================================================

  ! ****************************************************************
  SUBROUTINE add_node_at_head(p_head, idx_arg)
  ! ****************************************************************
    TYPE(LLnode),     POINTER, INTENT(INOUT) :: p_head
    INTEGER,                   INTENT(IN)    :: idx_arg
    !
    TYPE(LLnode),  POINTER :: p_new_head

    write(*,*) 'entered add_node_at_head..'

    allocate(p_new_head)
    p_new_head%idx = idx_arg
    p_new_head%next => p_head
    p_head => p_new_head

    write(*,*) '.. leaving add_node_at_head'

  END SUBROUTINE add_node_at_head



  ! ****************************************************************
  FUNCTION get_num_nodes(self) RESULT(num_nodes)
  ! ****************************************************************
    INTEGER                            :: num_nodes
    CLASS(LLnode), TARGET, INTENT(IN)  :: self
    !
    CLASS(LLnode), POINTER     :: p_node

    write(*,*) 'entered get_num_nodes ..'

    num_nodes = 0
    p_node => self
    do while (associated(p_node)) 
       num_nodes = num_nodes+1
       p_node => p_node%next
    end do

    write(*,*) '.. leaving get_num_nodes'

  END FUNCTION get_num_nodes


END MODULE tll
```

`main.f90`

```
PROGRAM main
  USE tll, ONLY : LLnode, add_node_at_head
  IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE(LLnode),  POINTER  :: p_head=>null()
  INTEGER                 :: num_nodes

  call add_node_at_head(p_head, 10)
  num_nodes= p_head%get_num_nodes() 
  write(*,*) 'num_nodes=', num_nodes

  write(*,*) 'Normal End.'

END PROGRAM main
```

Compilation and execution:

```
$ ifort -c tll.f90
$ ifort -c main.f90
$ ifort -o exe main.o tll.o
$ ./exe 
 entered add_node_at_head..
 .. leaving add_node_at_head
 entered get_num_nodes ..
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
exe                000000000046DF09  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                000000000046C7DE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                000000000043E3B2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                0000000000422FC3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                0000000000402A3B  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread.so.0    00002B8FDBB48330  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                00000000004026D2  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                0000000000402402  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                0000000000402336  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          00002B8FDBD77F45  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
exe                0000000000402229  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
$
```

Comment: Can you try with a much more recent version of ifort?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to a recent version now. Could someone try if the code looked valid?

Comment: The normal declaration of singly linked list I see are with `type` rather than `class`. Maybe the error is because `class` also refers to the extended types and in this case there are none. I am not sure though why it works with gfortran and not with ifort.

Comment: Crashes with ifort 16.0.1 on line 58. Please use debugging options when examining crashes, like `ifort -g -traceback -warn -check  ttl.f90 main.f90`. Probably worth to raise the issue with Intel on their support site.

Comment: Also crashes with 17.0.3 (finally I had chance to look).  I agree with the idea of going to Intel.